# Как анимировать элемент after с помощью css?

Tags: css3, анимация

Это простая линия, которая должна отрисоваться слева на право.

```css
.row {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #555556;
}

.row::before {
  background-color: #63ffd1;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 110px
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```css
.row {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #555556;
}

.row::before {
  background-color: #63ffd1;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 110px
  
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}
 

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {width: 0px;}
    to {width: 200px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {width: 0px;}
    to {width: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
```

Comment: А как скрыть элемент до определенного момента? Чтобы ег не было видно пока не пройдет задержка анимации animation-delay. А то получается что всю задержку он виден, а потом исчезает и проходит анимация.

Comment: Нашел. Это animation-fill-mode: both. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ВладимирКравченко нашли сами решение,- очень хорошо, а может оформите прямо здесь, отдельным ответом? Думаю это будет полезно многим.